# VBA Excel 2016 Creating a macro that calls a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Excel 2016
I use a user defined function to combine long lists of numbers and separate them with comas. It saves a lot of time with some of our older software. The function I’ve been using is here.

```vb
Function ConcatDelim(ConcatRange As Variant) As String

    Dim Test As Boolean
    Test = True
    
    For Each i In ConcatRange
        If Test Then
            ConcatDelim = i
            Test = False
        Else
            ConcatDelim = ConcatDelim & ", " & i
        End If
    Next i
    
End Function
```

I want to create a macro that uses this function on the currently selected cells, creates a new row at the top of the sheet and outputs the results in A1.

Here is what I have written for the macro.

```vb
Sub ConcatDelimMacro()
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
    'Concat Delim Function
    Dim SelectionRange As Range
    Dim varCellCount As Integer
    Dim ConcatString As String
    Set SelectionRange = Selection
    Set varCellCount = Count(SelectionRange)
    If varCellCount > 99 Then
        MsgBox "You have selected too many cells, please select 99 or fewer at a time"
    ElseIf varCellCount <= 99 Then
        Worksheets.Rows(1).Insert
        Concat = ConcatDelim(SelectionRange)
        Range(A1) = Concat
End Sub
```

I either get no results or a compile error "sub or function not defined". I have tried having the function and macro is the same module and in separate. I apologize I am not very experienced with VBA.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `varCellCount =SelectionRange.Cells.Count` without the `Set` as that's only used for object-type variables

Comment: Have you seen the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) function in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

```vb
Function ConcatDelim(ConcatRange As Variant) As String
    Dim sep As String, c As Range, v
    For Each c In ConcatRange.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)     'remove any extra spaces
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            ConcatDelim = ConcatDelim & sep & v
            sep = ","         'add delimiter after first non-blank value
        End If
    Next c
End Function


Sub ConcatDelimMacro()
    Dim ConcatString As String
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Please first select up to 99 cells"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Selection.Cells.Count > 99 Then
        MsgBox "You have selected too many cells, please select 99 or fewer at a time"
    Else
        ConcatString = ConcatDelim(Selection)
        With Selection.Parent 'parent = the worksheet where range is selected
            .Rows(1).Insert
            .Range("A1").Value = ConcatString
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```